# Reverse scrolling with HTML5

Tags: html, scroll

Is it possible to create a reverse scrolling effect with HTML5 and JavaScript on two parts of the screen, something like this? http://nationallgbtmuseum.org/#/home/

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override scrolling with jQuery. Simple like this:

```
​$(window).scroll(function() {
// TODO scrolling
});​​
```

If you want to create a page like you linked, you need two main section on your page. A left and a right side. While the left content is normally scrolled, you reverse the content of the right section, and every time when the window scrolled you need to get the offset-from top. After that you set the top position of the right section.
Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/338R8/25/